# Trouble compiling java 9 in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

I am trying toplay around with Java9 in the latest intellij (community edition):

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
Build #IC-163.7743.44, built on November 17, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b2 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Without writing any code:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
C:\Users\pisarevv\Desktop\jdk-9\bin\java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=1630946162877517857 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Djps.file.types.component.name=CommunityFileTypes -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2016.3 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\pisarevv\.IdeaIC2016.3\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\pisarevv\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/pisarevv/.IdeaIC2016.3/system/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/jre/jre" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_112-release -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/pisarevv/.IdeaIC2016.3/system/compile-server/_temp_ -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.experimental=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\pisarevv\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-451096579120734544-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Users/pisarevv/Desktop/jdk-9/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/ecj-4.6.1.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/openapi.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 62860 aa8c9c68-3477-48ea-9f1c-5086eaa5935d C:/Users/pisarevv/.IdeaIC2016.3/system/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Users/pisarevv/Desktop/jdk-9/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3/lib/ecj-4.6.1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:537)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.<clinit>(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.getUnsafe(ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.java:2787)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.<clinit>(ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.java:2752)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentIntObjectMap(ContainerUtil.java:2489)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentRefValueIntObjectHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentRefValueIntObjectHashMap.java:31)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentWeakValueIntObjectHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentWeakValueIntObjectHashMap.java:31)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentIntObjectWeakValueMap(ContainerUtil.java:2530)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Key.<clinit>(Key.java:38)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:82)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessor java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to unnamed module @4f9a3314
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.throwInaccessibleObjectException(Reflection.java:424)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:192)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:186)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.findMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:265)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:279)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.<clinit>(ReflectionUtil.java:422)
    ... 15 more
```

Does someone have an idea how to resolve this or should I simply wait until they release another version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been using a Java 9 Jigsaw build (from http://jdk9.java.net/jigsaw/) - IntelliJ does not work on it yet. This is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162653). You'll have to stick to the regular EA builds (from https://jdk9.java.net/download/).

Comment: Nicolai! Thanks for this :-). Your blog has been an excellent source for information about Java 9 in particular and about java in general. I follow it closely and you are doing a wonderful work.

Comment: To the issue: can you tell me what's the difference between the two builds?

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. :) The EA builds are created from different branches in the Java 9 code base. Up until a few months ago only the Jigsaw branch contained the module system. Then it was merged into the main branch but the Jigsaw branch still sees features of the module system earlier. I don't know which particular change causes the trouble, though. (Btw, this is the root problem: `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessor `.)

Comment: It seems that both sites now point to the same build (148). Neither works :-(

Comment: The build number is not the only part of their version string - this is an excerpt from running `java -version` on recent builds: `build 9-ea+146` vs `build 9-ea+146-jigsaw`. Only the build numbers are the same but their content is not because they are built from different branches. To answer your question: I have no idea which Jigsaw build is the most recent one to work with IntelliJ. Are you saying that using `build 9-ea+148` shows the same exception?

Comment: Yap :-) This is the output of java --version: *build 9-ea+148-jigsaw-nightly-h5824-20161208*

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue with ```OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)``` in intellij. Can you please suggest what needs to be done? Is this still a jigsaw issue in openjdk as well?

Comment: @SanjaySs If you have a recent IntelliJ version (2020.3 or 2021.1) and this error still exists (i.e. without writing any code, it crashes - which would surprise me), you may have to open an issue in [JetBrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Answer (score 0):

I also found this [comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205453570/comments/205127244) on JetBrains blog saying that IntelliJ IDEA will not be working with JDK9 build 148 and newer.We either should fallback to build 146 or wait on Intellij 2017.1 EAP.